# Write the VHDL text file for a 6-bit adder using INTEGER types

Tags: integer, vhdl, counter

I have this, but I don't think it is Integer type, any help appreciated?

```
entity counter is
    port (Incr., Load, Clock: in     bit;
          Carry:             out    bit;
          Data_Out:          buffer bit_vector(7 downto 0);
          Data_In:           in     bit_vector(7 downto 0));
end counter;
```

Comment: Why are you thinking in terms of integers only? Even bits can be added.

Comment: Also,you can't write `Incr.` in this way in declaration!

Answer (score 0):

Besides Incr. not being a valid VHDL identifier which cannot contain a '.' (use `Incr` without the period), you are using types with a base type of `bit` which require the use of package numeric_bit to perform vector to integer conversions.  Package numeric_bit serves the same purpose for types with a base type of bit that package numeric_std serves for types with a base type of std_ulogic (std_logic).

The use clause in your context clause would contain `ieee.numeric_bit.all;` and contain a library clause making library ieee visible (`library ieee;`) allowing arithmetic and math operations on bit_vector types.

You haven't declare `Data_In` or `Data_Out` to be a `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` value which implies any conversion to integer is likely unsigned.

You could also not that you have only one input port of type bit_vector which implies along with the presence of `INCR` that you're confining addition to increment, presumably by one.

Also note your 8 bit `Data_In` and `Data_Out` values are not necessary for an unsigned 6 bit add.  There are two ready possibilities.  You're either accumulating into an 8 bit value or you're simply connecting to 8 bit interfaces.  (There's also the possibility you've specified the wrong size in your port declaration).

You can read a dated version of source for package numeric_bit adequate for understanding how to convert to integer and back to bit_vector at [IEEE-SA Supplemental Material](https://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/), files numeric_bit.vhdl and numeric_bit_body.vhdl.  At least the declarations will be made available for reading by your VHDL tool vendor as well.

Conversion between a bit_vector and an integer would take the form of:

```
to_integer(unsigned(Data_In(5 downto 0)))
```

Which converts in this case 6 bits of Data_In to a natural, after which you could perform integer arithmetic.

There are several possible ways to express the storage for the accumulation, and because you've displayed `Data_Out` as mode `buffer` we can assume you meant to hold the value as a bit_vector, so the addition is expressed full of type conversions:

```
 1  library ieee;
 2  use ieee.numeric_bit.all;
 3  
 4  entity counter is
 5      port (
 6            Incr, Load, Clock: in     bit;
 7            Carry:             out    bit;
 8            Data_Out:          buffer bit_vector(7 downto 0);
 9            Data_In:           in     bit_vector(7 downto 0)
10      );
11  end entity;
12  
13  architecture foo of counter is
14      
15  begin
16      
17  ACCUM: 
18      process(Clock)
19          variable result: integer range 0 to 127;
20      begin
21          if Clock = '1' and Clock'EVENT then
22              if Load = '1' then 
23                  Data_Out <= Data_In;     -- without regard to 6 bit add 
24              elsif Incr = '1' then
25  
26                  result := to_integer(unsigned(Data_Out(5 downto 0)));  -- 6 bits
27                  result := result + 1;    -- normal arithmetic meaning
28  
29                  If result > 63 then
30                      Carry <= '1';        -- Carry is stored in a register bit
31                      result := result mod 64;  -- treat the result as 6 bits
32                                                -- prevents to_unsigned warning
33                  else
34                      Carry <= '0';
35                  end if;
36              
37                  Data_Out(5 downto 0) <= bit_vector(to_unsigned(result,6));
38                  Data_Out(7 downto 6) <= "00";
39              end if;  
40          end if;
41  
42      end process;
43      
44  end architecture;
45
```

*Note this implies a synchronous Load*

If on the other other hand if the parameters of this potential school assignment didn't require an interface expressed as bit_vectors, only required 6 bits or allowed the use of integer signals in the port interface list the design becomes simpler.

The integer to unsigned conversion routine to_unsigned can produce a warning if the input integer value is greater than can be expressed in the number of bits specified (6), so the result is 'clamped' to 6 bits with the `mod` operator.   This is pure behavioral modeling to prevent the warning whenever carry is set and that line could be commented out.

For purposes of expressing integers as bits following synthesis there's only 7 flip flops involved, the most significant output as `Carry`, the remaining 6 as `Data_Out(5 downto 0)`.

The above code analyzes (sans line numbers) and likely works.

Type conversions (bit_vector(expression), unsigned(expression) are allowed between closely related types having the same base type.

If you look at the source for to_integer in the body of package numeric_bit you'd find that conversion is done bit at a time and the length is known from the argument.  For conversion to_unsigned you supply the length as an additional argument (..., 6).

Personally I think it a bit more likely you (are) intended to use integer signals in the port interface where in you'd still need a result value that had an integer range greater than 6 bits allowing extraction of `Carry`.